# Find top log(n) or top sqt(n) values in an array of integers

Tags: c++, c, square-root

Do you understand what this question means

Find top log(n) or top sqt(n) values in an array of integers in less than linear time.

If you don't, here is the question http://www.careercup.com/question?id=9337669.

Could you please help me in understanding this question and then may be get it solved. (Although once i understand i might get it solved too)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the array is not sorted, This problem is `Omega(n)`, since you need to read all elements [finding max is `Omega(n)` problem in non-sorted array, and this problem is not easier then finding max]. So, there is no sublinear solution for it.

There is `O(n)` [linear] solution, using [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

```
1. find the log(n) biggest element. //or sqrt(n) biggest element...
2. scan the array and return all elements bigger/equal it.
```

(*)This pseudo code is not correct if the array contain dupes, but trimming the dupes in a second step is fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Amit. I couldn't understood this "scan the array and return all elements bigger/equal it.". What do you mean by 'it' here?

If i understood clearly
Does this question want me to return all elements in array which are > top log(n) or top sqt(n)?? 

Emilio above mentioned that all they want me to do is return the sqt[biggest element in array].

Comment: 'it' is the element found at step (1). The question asks for all values greater then `log(n)/sqrt(n)`, since it indicates: `Find top log(n) or top sqt(n) values....` and **not**: `Find top log(n) or top sqt(n) value` [asking for value**s** and not value]

Answer (score 6):

For non sorted array the complexity is linear, but it can be possible to improve the performance by observing that log(n) and sqrt(n) are both monotonic growing function, hence max(log(n),...) is also log(max(n,...)) and same for sqrt.

So just find max(n) (linearly) and calculate log and sqrt.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: true, but I'm not interested in the "rate", just to find a peak value.

Comment: Understood the question. Thanks.

Comment: but sqrt of 0 is 0 and it's log is INFINITY, we can include 0 in our array.